# Can a 14th level College of Creation Bard Create Five Summonable Items for Free with Creative Crescendo and Drawmij's Instant Summons?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting

> Creative Crescendo. At 14th level, when you use your Performance of Creation feature, you can create more than one item at once. The number of items equals your Charisma modifier (minimum of two items). If you create an item that would exceed that number, you choose which of the previously created items disappears. Only one of these items can be of the maximum size you can create; the rest must be Small or Tiny. You are no longer limited by gp value when creating items with Performance of Creation.

> Drawmij's Instant Summons. Components: V, S, M (a sapphire worth 1,000 gp).
> Duration: Until dispelled.
> You touch an object weighing 10 pounds or less whose longest dimension is 6 feet or less. The spell leaves an invisible mark on its surface and invisibly inscribes the name of the item on the sapphire you use as the material component. Each time you cast this spell, you must use a different sapphire.

Once a CoC Bard uses Creative Crescendo, their gold limit is removed, but their item limit is only expanded to the amount equal to your Charisma modifier, minimum of two. Assuming a Charisma stat of 20, modifier +5, **can a CoC Bard have five summonable items for free, in addition to any extraneously purchased sapphires and casts of Drawmij's Instant Summons?**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Yes, items from Creative Crescendo work as material components

A good comparator is the wizard spell [creation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/creation), which has explicit language that the items created with it cannot be used as material components:

> Using any material created by this spell as another spell's material component causes that spell to fail.

The Creative Crescendo feature does not have such language, so you are free to use the objects created with it as material components for spells, and that includes components that have a gp value (wether they are consumed, or not).

If you use it with *Instant Summons*, and your bard has a Charisma bonus of +5, you can create and maintain up to 5 sapphires at any time, in addition to any other sapphires that you otherwise procured.

Typically you would want to have the sapphires to stay around a long time, so you can summon the object whenever you need. As the item from Performance of Creation "*disappears after a number of hours equal to your proficiency bonus*", and the duration is not changed by Creative Crescendo, the benefit of this for this application would be somewhat limited (especially as when the sapphire vanishes, so does your means to summon your object).

If you use it for spells that consume their components, such as *resurrection* that needs a 1,000 gp diamond, you essentially have a way around the cost of the material component.